# Multiprocessing Process leaving behind zombies after join

Tags: python, unix, process, multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing to spawn off some CPU intensive work in a separate process but what I'm seeing is that once I join the spawned process a zombie remains. I wonder if I'm missing something or doing something wrong with the library. My code looks something like:

```
def worker(stuff, q):
  #CPU intensive stuff goes here
  q.put(res)

def parent:
  q = Queue()
  p = Process(target=worker, args=(stuff, q))
  p.start()
  res = q.get()
  p.join()
  #Continue with processing
```

I get the result just fine out of the queue but when I take a look at my ps output I see a zombie instance of the interpreter for every instance I ran. Is there something I'm missing that I forgot to cleanup?

Comment: The zombie exist because it expects that the parent process will eventually come and ask what the exit code of its child was. Until it asks, or until the parent dies, the zombie stays. So, you have  ask the childs how it went (you may need to keep track of the childs PID). Check the bash/wait command to understand what to do (I know you are not using bash but that can help you understand what has to be done).

Comment: The code you posted doesn't quite work - but with a bit of fixing, it works without producing a zombie (at least on linux, not sure what flavor of unix you use). You don't need any more cleanup.